# Php How to get a radio button working

Tags: php

I have a form that has radio buttons but the $_GET for that form doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
<?php $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";    

<form action="<?php $actual_link ?>" method="get" id="form_details" name="details" class="form_details_class">
        <p class="yes_no_float_right">No</p><p class="yes_no_float_right">Yes</p><br>
        <p>Show File Details:     <input type="radio" id="details_radio_a" class="details_radio" value="1" name="details_radio"/><input type="radio" id="details_radio_a" class="details_radio" value="0" name="details_radio"/></p><br>
        <p>Show Tails:            <input type="radio" id="details_radio_b" class="details_radio" value="1" name="tails_radio"/>  <input type="radio" id="details_radio_b" class="details_radio" value="0" name="tails_radio"/></p><br>
        <p>Show Public or Private:<input type="radio" id="details_radio_c" class="details_radio" value="1" name="porp_radio"/>   <input type="radio" id="details_radio_c" class="details_radio" value="0" name="porp_radio"/></p><br>
    </form> 

<?php if (isset($_GET['details_radio'])) 
{ 
    $details_radio = $_GET['details_radio'];
    //echo '<div class="moveto" id="moveto">Select a folder to Move To and click Proceed...</div>';
    $rowid = 1;
    if($details_radio == '0')
    {
        echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">details_radio = 0</div>';
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$username_options." SET details_radio=? WHERE rowid=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $details_radio, $rowid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {   
        echo '<br><p class="colourful">details_radio = 1</p><br>';
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$username_options." SET details_radio=? WHERE rowid=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $details_radio, $rowid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Two things. The `$_GET['details_radio']` doesn't seem to be working for the form and two, takes some explaining.

The program is a gallery. When the user clicks on an album and views those images, the program is on the same page but displaying different media. When the user clicks on the radio `submit` button, the page is refreshed back to the original page view, which is "main". Instead when a user presses `submit` on the radio buttons form, I want the page to refresh the current view, which would be the same view he is viewing (which would be some images inside say Album 1).

How could I get the `$_GET['details_radio']` to work and what should I use to refresh the page's current view instead of refreshing the whole page? I am currently using `<?php $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>` as the form refresher.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your fields are `details_radio`, `tails_radio` and `porp_radio`, but you are trying to get the field values with `details_radio`, which is the id of the radio options. Form values get passed by name, not id (also, element ids must be unique; yours are not).

Incidentally, a cool trick to have a form submit to the same page is to simple set the form action to `?` - it's dirty, but it's completely valid HTML and works.

Comment: 1. I did try your suggestion previous to this post and it doesn't seem to work. I tried it again just in case E.g. I changed the element ID's to `details_radio_a`, `details_radio_b` and `details_radio_c` and left the names as `details_radio` and it still didn't seem to update.